# Can corrupted MacBook1,1 graphics be fixed?

Tags: macbook-pro, graphics

Can the graphics on this 2008 MacBook1,1 be fixed? I believe the OS version is Leopard with all Leopard updates installed. Everything looks fine through entering your password at the login screen, then the wallpaper appears, and the mouse, but all the graphics are corrupted after that, like so:
[image: good graphics before login]
[image: bad graphics after login]
It is very hot here right now, could this be overheating damage? I tried resetting PRAM/NVRAM, next I will try some kind of restore with the Leopard DVD...

Comment: Have you tried logging in while holding down the shift key to prevent launch-on-login apps from running? If that doesn't work, try rebooting while holding down shift to prevent launch-on-boot apps from running.

Answer (score 1):

I would try erasing the Mac and reinstalling the OS

Comment: This seems quite extreme for a first step.